# Fedora Equivalent of prstat /truss

Tags: c++, c, linux, monitoring, fedora

Is there any command in Fedora core (10) which displays the system call being executed ? Scouring the internet only reveals top and likes...

Comment: if you execute a command, there can no other system call be executed at the same time, or am I missing something?

Comment: Whaaaat? Are you using MS-DOS?

Comment: @Ronny : When any executable is run , it more or less ends up using underlying kernel/system calls...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [**strace**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) ?